# indexPathForItemAtPoint Occasionally Returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

In my app I have a `UICollectionView` which acts as a scrolling color-picker in my app.  I'm having a very rare bug where once in a blue moon the color will be set to the first value in the scroller upon button press, rather than the one associated with the button the user actually touched.

I isolated this to `indexPathForItemAtPoint` returning `nil` for the button press.

For now I've hacked around the problem by simply returning when the index path returned is `nil`, however, I'm concerned this behavior is still not correct for a couple reasons;

1. First of all, I looked at the touch position in the debugger and it is valid within the bounds of the collection view.
2. Second, the trigger to get the color associated with the button occurs when the event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` happens for one of the buttons in the collection.  It therefore doesn't make sense to me that the code would be called for a touch not inside a button.  In this case I've swapped my current bug of getting the wrong color for a bug where a button will rarely not be responsive.

I did a bit of searching and unless I missed it, all I've seen on this site are cases where the code had an implementation error and was *always* receiving nil, but nothing quite like this.

I was hoping someone might be able to help me identify a cause so I can fix it or at least understand why the issue is occurring.

The relevant functions are included below:

```
- (IBAction)myClickEvent:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView: self.collectionViewColors];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionViewColors indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

    if(!indexPath)return;

    appState.currentColor = appState.colors[indexPath.row];

    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(appState.currentColor.CGColor);

    self.redSlider.value = components[0];
    self.greenSlider.value = components[1];
    self.blueSlider.value = components[2];

    appState.setBackgroundImagePreview(nil);
}
```

And the initialization function which sets the button event:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    [myButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(myClickEvent:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    /// abridged 

    [myButton setBackgroundImage:colorSquare forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: I tried the following to get the touches, thinking that Apple might be sending multitouch / touches outside the button for some reason.  No dice.  It still returns a `nil` index path on occasion.

```
 NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender];
```

Comment: Have you tried the other common way of getting the point with `CGPoint p = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];` to see if that works any better?

Comment: I just tried that;  It's hard to say for sure since it's a tough bug to reproduce, but it really seems to not be doing this any more!  I wish I knew why the other method was not as reliable, but I'll put this patch in and post again if I find any problem.

Answer (score 3):

`indexPathForItemAtPoint:` returns `nil` if "[no item was found at the specified point](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForItemAtPoint:)" which is most commonly the case when the point falls in the spacing between cells.  There are 3 flow layout properties that are commonly used to influence how cells are spaced:

- `minimumLineSpacing`
- `minimumInteritemSpacing`
- `sectionInset`

When you get a `nil` index path and then ask for its row, it will always be `0` and thus `appState.colors[indexPath.row]` gives you the first color in your array.

---

One way to fix this would be to loop over all cells in `indexPathsForVisibleItems` and determine which one contains the center point (if any) or is closest to it.  To easiest way to do that is with 
[`- layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:), `CGRectContainsPoint()`, and some easy math.

It could also make sense for your app to simply `return` if you get a `nil` path and take no action.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem which was precisely that I was asking for an index path at a point between two cells. I implemented a category on UICollectionView called indexPathForCellNearestPoint: using the tips above, and it works.

Comment: @jszumski Could you please elaborate on the precise usage of layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: and CGRectContainsPoint()?  When trying to find the closest cell center, can we just compute minimum distance?  
        for (NSIndexPath* path in [self indexPathsForVisibleItems])
        {
            cell = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
            distance = powf(cell.center.x - point.x, 2) + powf(cell.center.y - point.y, 2);
            if (distance < closestDistance)
            {
                closestDistance = distance;
                closestPath = path;
            }
        }

Comment: @Cindeselia That's really up to whatever makes sense for your app.  Can you create a new question with more specifics and link it here?